# Start web app on Raspberry Pi

Tags: web, interface, raspberry-pi, boot

I'm currently putting together a project where my application will have a web based frontend and will be running on a microcontroller. In order to provide a friendly UI I would like my app UI to startup without showing any Unix screens, such as splash screen, login and BIOS. This is supposed to behave as an embedded system.

Since my app is browser dependent, I presume I'm going to need my Linux graphical desktop environment running in the background but the less I have running the better.

What is the best OS Rasberry PI for this purpose and how do I make it behave as an embedded system?

Thanks in advance.

regards,
ForeignerBR

Answer (score 0):

Your solution could likely be the following:
Raspbian is the most supported operating system on the Pi at this time and most Linux Debian applications are on there. For speed Arch is the best (but has no GUI as standard).

You could then get it to login & start up into X11 automatically and then set it to launch up the web browser.

I would recommend chromium as you can start it up into a full screen Kiosk mode via the command line. So at boot it would show the command line and possibly the start of a GUI but once booted up should just display the browser.

Hope This Helps - 
Ryan Walmmsley